# Constraining a generic type argument to numeric types

Tags: c#, generics

I'm defining a generic type:

```
public class Point<T> where T : IConvertible, IComparable
```

What I would really like to do is constrain T to be a numeric type (one of the ints or floats.) There's no INumeric in the CLR. Is there an interface or collection of interfaces that could be used here to constrain the type to one of the boxed numeric classes?

Comment: This cannot be done in C#. The most you can do it have a new IPoint interface that can enforce it

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Generic Interface for Numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325131/c-generic-interface-for-numbers)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  This has been a [highly requested feature](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94264/arithmetic-types-like-int-double-decimal-should-implement-iarithmetic-t) for a long time.

Right now, the best option is likely to use:

```
where T : struct, IConvertible, IComparable<T>
```

(The struct constraint prevents string usage...)

However, this still allows any user defined value type that implements the appropriate constraints to be used.

Comment: IConvertible would be the big one that would, on top of the rest, prevent non-numeric type use. I can't think of too many user-defined types, outside possibly "unit-of-measure"-type structs like Money, that would bother implementing this interface; it's quite possibly the largest built-in interface contract in .NET.

Comment: String implements IConvertible and is a non-numeric type.

Comment: @phoog: That's specifically why I suggested adding the struct constraint - it prevents string from being used...

Comment: Sorry Reed, that comment should have been directed @KeithS.

Answer (score 1):

`where T: struct` will constrain it to a value type.

Comment: It could still be any user-defined struct, as well as built-in non-numeric structs like DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

One - not very comfortable way - is to check the valid type in the constructor and throw an exception. It works, but it isn't "compiler-safe" and produces runtime errors. :-(

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do it. 
You can choose where `T:struct,IConvertible,IFormattable,IComparable` to restrict it to all blittable numeric types and enums, but even if you did the restriction you still can't use operators on `T` as the operators are all static.

E.g.

```
point.X-point.Y
```

Would be illegal as generics don't know about static members.