# Why my Generic Extension Method says cannot convert from T to ..... or .... to T

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

Further to my questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241345/any-percentage-function-in-net

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942202/percentage-of-each-element-in-linq

i want to create a generic extension method in .Net 4.0 which will generate percentage of the list items to the sum of the list. This list will be of Numeric types only.

My code is

```
public static T Percentage<T>(this T array) where T: ? // What should come in place of ? 
{
  double[] darray = (double[])T; // Error convert type 'T' to 'double[]'

  darray = darray.Select(x=> x * 100 / darray.Sum()).ToArray();

  return darray; // Error convert type 'double[]' to 'T'
}
```

I want to call it like

```
double[] MD = {8.0,21.0,25.0,13.0,26.0,37.0,37.0,33.0,71.0,9.0};

MD = MD.Percentage().ToArray();
```

What am i doing wrong;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot constrain types by "numeric" values. It is somewhat of a limitation of the framework.

Your best best is to do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<double> Percentage(this IEnumerable<int> values)
{
    var sum = values.Sum();
    return values.Select(v => (double)v / (double)sum).ToArray();
}

public static IEnumerable<double> Percentage(this IEnumerable<long> values)
{
    var sum = values.Sum();
    return values.Select(v => (double)v / (double)sum).ToArray();
}

public static IEnumerable<double> Percentage(this IEnumerable<double> values)
{
    var sum = values.Sum();
    return values.Select(v => v / sum).ToArray();
}
```

Essentially you need to produce an overload for each type you want to support.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to have constrain of type you want. Check out [Constraining a generic type argument to numeric types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157025/constraining-a-generic-type-argument-to-numeric-types) for details.

Since there are not too many numeric types (int/float/double/decimal) it may be easier to simply provide concrete implementations.

More options

- require IConvertable and use [IConvertible.ToDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.todouble.aspx) to perform all math in doubles
- use https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html mentioned here [C#: Generic Interface for Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325131/c-generic-interface-for-numbers).

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative that works, which is to pass in the selector function that allows you to convert to doubles when you call Percentage. This is the extension method:

```
public static double[] Percentage<T>(this T[] array, Func<T,double> selector)
{
    var doubles = array.Select(selector);
    var sum = doubles.Sum();

    var result = doubles.Select(x => x * 100 / sum).ToArray();

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
    double[] MD = {8.0,21.0,25.0,13.0,26.0,37.0,37.0,33.0,71.0,9.0};
var MDPercent = MD.Percentage(x => x).ToArray();
```

And then you can have a simple double version:

```
public static double[] Percentage(this double[] array)
{
    return Percentage(array, x => x);
}
```

Or an int version:

```
public static double[] Percentage(this int[] array)
{
    return array.Percentage(x => (double)x);
}
```

Which are simpler to use:

```
var MDPercent = MD.Percentage().ToArray();
```