# Discussion on generic numeric type in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I wonder if there is a way, in C#, to have a type based on a primitive type, and duplicate it to use other primitives instead.

I know it's not very clear, I don't really know how to explain this (and english is not my mother-tongue, sorry for that...), so I'll try to explain it using pseudo-code.

A quick example:

```
public struct Vector2d {
    public double X;
    public double Y;

    //Arithmetic methods: Length, normalize, rotate, operators overloads, etc...
}
```

The problem is that I'd like to have a float and a int32 version of this type.

What i'm doing actually (valid C# code):

```
//This type contains all useful methods
public struct Vector2d {
    public float X;
    public float Y;

    public Vector2f AsFloat() {
        return new Vector2f((float)X, (float)Y);
    }
    public Vector2f AsInteger() {
        return new Vector2i((int)X, (int)Y);
    }

    //Arithmetic methods
}

//These types are only here to be casted from/to, all the arithmetics methods are on the double-based type
public struct Vector2f {
    public float X;
    public float Y;

    public Vector2f AsDouble() {
        return new Vector2d(X, Y);
    }
    public Vector2f AsInteger() {
        return new Vector2i((int)X, (int)Y);
    }
}
public struct Vector2i {
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public Vector2f AsFloat() {
        return new Vector2f(X, Y);
    }
    public Vector2f AsDouble() {
        return new Vector2d(X, Y);
    }
}
```

It works but it's not "sexy", and in case of extensive casts using the AsXXX methods, there will inevitably be an impact on performances.

Ideally, I would have arithmetics methodes on all of three types, but it would be a pain to maintain...

What would be the ideal solution (pseudo-code, not valid C#):

```
public struct Vector2<T> where T : numeric {
    public T X;
    public T Y;

    public T Length {
        return (T)Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y);
    }
    //Other arithmetic methods
}
```

I know this isn't possible in C# for the moment, but here is the true question:

**Do you have any idea on how to nicely and efficiently handle this ?**

What I've been thinking to (pseudo-code, not valid C#) :

```
//The TYPE defined constant should be used by Vector2Body instead of plain typed "double", "float", etc...

public struct Vector2d {
    #define TYPE double
    #import Vector2Body
}

public struct Vector2f {
    #define TYPE float
    #import Vector2Body
}

public struct Vector2i {
    #define TYPE int
    #import Vector2Body
}
```

That way, I wouldn't have duplicated code, easier to maintain

Waiting for your ideas :)

PS: If a moderator have ideas on how to better format my question, feel free to edit it :)

Comment: I'm thinking `Vector2<T> where T : IConvertible`

Comment: There are ways just search "[C#] [generics] numbers" and you get multiple results. But it will severely impact performance. And considering you want working with vectors, performance is first concern here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Generic Interface for Numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325131/c-generic-interface-for-numbers)

Comment: I don't have occasion to use them much, but a T4 template could do the job.

Comment: Why do you need int and float version? May be there is another way of solving your problem.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+numeric+generic+constraint

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM Nothing specifical, these are types in a Math library I'm working on, and dependly on usage that will be done of that, you may want to have a float or a int version. First example that comes to me is for Graphics API such as OpenGL... In that case you probably want to work with floats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a very nice approach given by **@mike-z** , using T4 templates:

The template (.tt file):

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
using System;

namespace My.Math {
<# Vector2Body("d", "double"); #>
<# Vector2Body("f", "float"); #>
<# Vector2Body("i", "int"); #>
}

<#+ private void Vector2Body(string suffix, string t) { #>

    public struct Vector2<#= suffix #> {
        public <#= t #> X;
        public <#= t #> Y;

        //Arithmetic for <#= t #>...
    }

<#+ } #>
```

And the auto generated code:

```
using System;

namespace My.Math {

    public struct Vector2d {
        public double X;
        public double Y;

        //Arithmetic for double...
    }


    public struct Vector2f {
        public float X;
        public float Y;

        //Arithmetic for float...
    }


    public struct Vector2i {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        //Arithmetic for int...
    }

}
```

No generic, so no performance impact, code written once...

Comment: Now the only little thing wrong with that method, is the lack of synthax highlighting when working on the .tt file, but since the .cs is auto generated each time you save the .tt file, and the .cs, it, has synthax highlighting...

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was thinking. I will just add that you may want to look into partial classes (or structs, here) and partial methods if you want to customize the generated code at all.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like,

```
public struct Vector2<T> where T : IConvertible
{
    private readonly double x;
    private readonly double y;

    public Vector2(T x, T y)
    {
        this.x = x.ToDouble(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        this.y = y.ToDouble(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }

    public T X
    {
        get
        {
            return ConvertBack(this.x);
        }
    }

    public T Y
    {
        get
        {
            return ConvertBack(this.y);
        }
    }

    private static T ConvertBack(double d)
    {
        return (t)Convert.ChangeType(d, typeof(T), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); 
    }
}
```

but, if you don't want generic treatment. Then you might as well have several specialized `Vector2` types.

Comment: Very interesting approach. What would be the performance impact on intensive usage ?

Comment: @ingham the conversions have got to slow things down. Generics in general don't have a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about the same solution as Jodrell suggested.
Just want to add:

```
private Vector2(double x, double y)
{
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
}

public Vector2<E> ToVector<E>() where E : IConvertible
{
 return  new Vector2<E>(x, y);
}
```